# Assigning an icon instead of text for ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to replace the link text in here with a class that contains an icon:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", 
                  "EditSatelliteMeeting", 
                  "ByLaws", 
                   new { id = meeting.BLClubSatelliteMeetingId, 
                         ByLawsId = Model.ByLawsId }, 
                   new { @class = "js-openDialog", 
                         data_dialog_id = "AddSatelliteMeetingDialog",
                         data_dialog_title = "Edit  Satellite Meeting" })
```

I understand that to do this a common solution is to use `@Url.Action`.

But when I try to do this I get a parser error.

This breaks

```
<a href="@Url.Action("EditSatelliteMeeting", "ByLaws", 
                     new { id = meeting.BLClubSatelliteMeetingId, 
                           ByLawsId = Model.ByLawsId }, 
                     new { @class = "js-openDialog icon edit", 
                          data_dialog_id = "AddSatelliteMeetingDialog",
                          data_dialog_title = "Edit  Satellite Meeting" })"></a>
```

So does this

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("EditSatelliteMeeting", "ByLaws", 
                       new { id = meeting.BLClubSatelliteMeetingId, 
                             ByLawsId = Model.ByLawsId, 
                             @class = "js-openDialog icon edit", 
                             data_dialog_id = "AddSatelliteMeetingDialog",
                             data_dialog_title = "Edit  Satellite Meeting" })"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `a` + `Url.Action` instead of `Html.ActionLink`, then you can put the HTML attributes directly into the a-tag.

```
<a class = "js-openDialog icon edit"
   data_dialog_id = "AddSatelliteMeetingDialog"
   data_dialog_title = "Edit  Satellite Meeting"
   href='@Url.Action("EditSatelliteMeeting", "ByLaws", 
             new { id = meeting.BLClubSatelliteMeetingId, 
                   ByLawsId = Model.ByLawsId })'>
    <!-- icon here -->
</a>
```

There's no `Url.Action` overload that contains HTML attributes, which makes sense, because you can't put HTML attributes into a URL string.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got a decent result by trying this - works on localhost!:

```
 <a href="../Controller(Home)/View(Index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
```